# Battery usage problem in Android 2.3.6

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery, battery-life

Since the update to Gingerbread the battery of my phone has the half duration than with the 2.3.4 version.

The "Battery Usage" in settings don't show anything abnormal.

Anybody have the same problem? What can I do?

Edit:
My device is an HTC - Nexus One

Comment: i've had this problem with CM7, but it depends. As in my phone behaves like an old woman, happy on few days and giving a good battery backup and angry on others and killing it real quick.

Comment: Jajaja. I think there is a problem with the "Battery Usage", now it show my the Maps app at the top of the list! I don't open this app since two days! I waiting for a savior update that fix this =/

Comment: @GojaN: What device are you using?

Comment: @AlEverett I edit the question to answer your question. Anyhow, this question has some time and there seems not be any progress. May this question be closed?

Comment: @GojaN: Why close it? Someone may still come along with a solution. It's not like we have a limited number of questions we can have open.

Answer (score 1):

Check native email app. Sometimes it starts running and never stops, eating the battery to the end. I don't know how to solve it, so I keep checking and killing it when it starts to behave like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can download & install the app BetterBatteryStats from XDA:

> BetterBatteryStats - 
>   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809

from the app you can see the partial wakelocks and whats the program that use most of them.
After using this program and found the app that causes the battery drain, you can uninstall and then re install it or freeze it.

Answer (score -1):

Install some Task Killer (I use Advanced Task Killer), change its settings to see low level/system processes too and see the loads of processes running in background. Terminate the unnecessary ones, if required.

Comment: You shouldn't ever run a task killer.

Comment: Why? Can't I run it for user installed apps?